# Ruby permutation speed increase... the most popular first

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0

```
x = ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a + ('0'..'9').to_a    
popular=['abc','123','lol','cat','dog','mom','dd']

popular.each{|y| puts y};
x.permutation(3){|z|
   if not popular.include?(z.join)
      puts z.join
   end
}



abc
123
Lol
cat
dog
mom
dad
ABC
ABD
ABE
ABF
ABG
ABH
ABI
...
```

I have created a most popular list of arrays. I hope to process these first in the permutation and keep it as a enumerator.
the above is my best working example.

the example above is small scale.
my popular array is HUGE (250,000 size) and my permutation is more like 2**24... so the permutation loop will check if popular.include?(z.join)... this happens over a million times(crazy slow)... my mcahine will take 8 hours to complete...

(i want to share a performance boost with permutation, that i hope some one will find usefull)
trying to compute 2 elements 24 deep is the confertable limits of my machine.

```
Benchmark.realtime{
         ['z','y'].repeated_permutation(24){|x| x.join}
        }
#=> 28.231131836 "28 seconds"
#generated 2**24 => (16777216 uniq combinations)


puts Benchmark.realtime{
buf=[0,1].repeated_permutation(12).map(&:join)
        buf.repeated_permutation(2){|x| x.join}
        }
#=> 10.07396029 "10 seconds, way quicker"
#generated 2**12*2 (16777216 uniq combinations)
```

Comment: Show examples of your expected result.

Comment: I have updated the post with example output.

Comment: popular.each{|y| puts y}; x.permutation.{|z| if not popular.include?(z.join); puts z.join; end}# this should output what I'm looking for but can be time consuming if popular is large and the permutations has to process all combinations still

Comment: I would also like to incorporate opencl, to speed up computing of a permutation. I found rubicl on github

Comment: You can build your array more cleanly using: `x = [*'A'..'B', *'a'..'b', *'0'..'1'] # => ["A", "B", "a", "b", "0", "1"]`

Comment: Please don't put additional requirements in the comments. Instead, edit your question and add them as if they were part of the original question. Don't add "Edit:" or "Update:" tags since we can see that something has changed and we have the ability to look at the revisions if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my question. I hope some one can provide help. my searching for identical problems, I found a suggestion for lazy enum but I'm not sure how to implement this. If I need to post my real life much larger example. Let me know...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not how you're generating the permutation, though that could be made better.  The problem is what you're doing for each permutation, specifically `Array.include?`.

To get a realistic benchmark we need to get your list of popular items larger.  This will make the differences in efficiencies between Array and other data structures more prominent.  I'm grabbing all the 4 letter words from my dictionary which is 5272 words.

```
popular_array = File.open("/usr/share/dict/words", "r").select { |word|
  word.strip!
  word.size == WORD_SIZE
}
```

Then I've bumped the `WORD_SIZE` up to 4 so we now have 13,388,280 permutations which is pretty close to 2**24 (16.8 million).

**The biggest problem is `popular.include?`.** For an `Array` this is an O(n) operation, the whole `popular` array has to be scanned for every permutation.  Instead of doing 13 million operations **you're doing 70 billion!**  As `popular` gets bigger, your code will get much slower.

To avoid this, put all the popular items in a hash and check `popular[candidate]`.  Hash lookups are O(1), no matter how large the hash gets it will always be the same speed to look up a key.

```
popular_hash = Hash.new
popular_array.each { |k|
  popular_hash[k] = 1
}
```

Your performance shoots up from "didn't wait for it to complete" (probably a few hours) to 20 seconds.

```
# Print to /dev/null to ignore IO performance
dev_null = File.open('/dev/null', 'a')

Benchmark.benchmark(CAPTION, 15, FORMAT) { |bench|
  bench.report("Hash#[]") {
    x.permutation(WORD_SIZE){|z|
      candidate = z.join
      if not popular_hash[candidate]
        dev_null.puts(candidate)
      end
    }
  }

  bench.report("Array#include?:") {
    x.permutation(WORD_SIZE){|z|
      candidate = z.join
      if not popular_array.include?(candidate)
        dev_null.puts(candidate)
      end
    }
  }
}

$ ruby ~/tmp/test.rb
Popular words (array): 5272
Popular words (hash): 5272
Words to check: 13388280
                      user     system      total        real
Hash#[]          22.090000   0.210000  22.300000 ( 22.610617)
Array#include?:
```

The good news is now your performance will scale linearly with the size of the candidate list.  The number of popular words has no effect.  2**24 is about 16 million so it should complete in less than a minute.

---

You might notice another small change.  Rather than calling `z.join` twice, I've called it once and stored it in a variable.  This saves about 10 seconds.  *Anything* you can do to avoid doing work inside that permutation loop will net big savings.

```
Benchmark.benchmark(CAPTION, 15, FORMAT) { |bench|
  bench.report("z.join twice:") {
    x.permutation(WORD_SIZE){|z|
      if not popular_hash[z.join]
        dev_null.puts(z.join)
      end
    }
  }

  bench.report("z.join once:") {
    x.permutation(WORD_SIZE){|z|
      candidate = z.join
      if not popular_hash[candidate]
        dev_null.puts(candidate)
      end
    }
  }
}

$ ruby ~/tmp/test.rb
Popular words (array): 5272
Popular words (hash): 5272
Words to check: 13388280
                      user     system      total        real
z.join twice:    30.550000   0.290000  30.840000 ( 31.176750)
z.join once:     22.370000   0.220000  22.590000 ( 22.901699)
```

---

A final note: when Benchmarking **ignore the "real" time** aka "wallclock".  This is the time which has passed in reality to do the work.  This might seem like a better measure, but for most things it produces inaccurate benchmarks.  The "real" time a computer takes will change if the computer does other stuff.  For example, if in the middle of your benchmark you were listening to music, that would effect your benchmark.  If during one benchmark it was running some system garbage collection routine and not during the other, that would skew your benchmarks and make one look slower or faster.

[Look at CPU time and system time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time#Subdivision).  Very roughly, CPU time says how much processing power was directly used in that process, and system time is how much work the kernel did in system calls for that process.

"Real" time only becomes relevant when benchmarking things like database, network and IO calls.  None of that will show up as CPU or system time.  Even then there are more reliable ways to benchmark their performance.

Comment: Omg you are amazing... completed in a few seconds... I new that array.include was the problem. Hash is a new thing for me... I hope to use this more often... thanks for your help

Comment: It's a shame that Enumerable doesn't include a `-` method.  Then you could do `x.permutation(WORD_SIZE) - popular` and let Ruby optimize it (probably by building a hash just like we did).

Comment: buf=x.repeated_permutated(WORD_SIZE/2).map(&:join)... then run this buff threw the permutation(2) improved the speed even more and allows  me to compute even larger  ;-] i need to read the docs on hash's

Comment: @BigmacBigmac I saw that earlier and ran some tests. It's very strange that it performs better. It seems to work, but I'd double check you're getting the same results.

Comment: I have checked. lets say your goal is 2 chars 20 deep... 2 ** 20=>1048576 your permutation loops this many times..... OR 2 ** 10=>1024 you now have all ten in length pre computed buffer... to get your goal of 20 in length 1024 * 2=> 2048 your loop now only needs to spin threw your hash 2048 times.